# SQL Counting A Column With Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My directions are: "Print an ordered list of instructors and the number of A's they assigned to the students. Order the output by number of A's (lowest to highest) and ignore instructors with no A's assigned"

This is what I have (http://pastebin.com/pKwc6cSK):

```
Use Student_Course59
SELECT INSTRUCTOR
FROM Section RIGHT OUTER JOIN Grade_report
ON Section.SECTION_ID = Grade_report.SECTION_ID
WHERE GRADE IS NOT NULL
AND INSTRUCTOR IS NOT NULL
```

Here are my Tables:

[image]

I cant figure out how to count how many A's a specific instructor has assigned.
Thanks so much!!

Comment: I assume INSTRUCTOR is in the SECTION table and GRADE is in the GRADE_REPORT table, which is why you need both tables. Okay so far, but you shall select A grades. Where is this in your query? Then you shall ignore those instructors who have not given any A's at all. So why do you outer join? You would need an outer join precisely in the opposite situation when you *had* to select them. Try harder and come back, if you need further assistance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this query to find a specific instructor has assigned.

```
SELECT INSTRUCTOR FROM Section 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Grade_report 
ON Section.SECTION_ID = Grade_report.SECTION_ID 
WHERE Grade_report.GRADE IS NOT NULL AND 
Section.INSTRUCTOR IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot it looks like you're running a version of SQL Server. If this is SQL Server 2005 or higher you can now use SUM as a "window function" which means it can take the OVER (PARTITION BY) meaning something like this might work:

Note the syntax is taken from your example, but if you'd provided a fiddler example, it would have worked better :)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT INSTRUCTOR, SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY INSTRUCTOR) AS SUM
FROM    Section
LEFT JOIN Grade_report ON Section.SECTION_ID = Grade_report.SECTION_ID
WHERE INSTRUCTOR IS NOT NULL
```

Note that I do not also know how your grade is represented so the value for 'A' might be different of course.

What it is doing is selecting all instructors and their grades. When the grade is 'A' it'll assign 1 otherwise 0 and then it'll SUM them up "partitioned by" (essentially a group by) instructor

You can solve a lot of problems using the OVER (PARTITION BY) in SQL Server so even if my syntax is incorrect for your case, try checking out the window functions and seeing if they cannot help you onwards.